# Mapping Google Drive as Network Drive without syncing

Tags: g-suite

I'm trying to learn if there's any way to map Google Drive on a client Windows workstation as a network drive without actually having to sync any files.

We have a NAS on-site that syncs with Google Drive, so what we're hoping to do is allow access to Google Drive when employees are working remotely, thereby removing the need for a VPN.

Is this possible?

I know how to install Google Drive and selectively sync folders, but that's not a viable option, as all of the folders need to show up on the employees workstation so that they can easily browse / copy / save files in those folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell, **no**, this is not possible. There are 3rd party applications that may or may not achieve this functionality, but if you want to map Google Drive as a network drive without 3rd party apps, then you'll need the data to actually download / sync to your computer.